# .desktop file will not launch the desired program, despite being identical in syntax to a working file

Tags: permissions, executable, desktop

I have a game executable at `~/Games/factorio/bin/x64/factorio` that I want to run from `dmenu`. I've created the shortcut below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Factorio
Path=/home/[USERNAME]/Games/factorio/bin/x64
Exec=factorio
Terminal=false
```

...with `[USERNAME]` obviously being my username. `dmenu` picks up the file and displays the entry, but when I select it, nothing happens. I created another desktop file for `pavucontrol` below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=pavucontrol
Comment=Sound manager for PulseAudio
Path=/usr/bin
Exec=pavucontrol
Terminal=false
```

This desktop file (`pavucontrol.desktop`) has the exact same syntax as `factorio.desktop`, yet actually works. Is there something I'm missing? I've checked the file permissions for both `factorio` and `factorio.desktop`, and both have full read permissions and write permissions for the owner. Both are marked as executable.

Here is some system information if that helps:

```
OS: Antergos Linux x86_64
Model: NC839AA-ABA a6838f
Kernel: 4.12.3-1-ARCH
Shell: bash 4.4.12
DE: i3
```

Comment: Check that square brackets and spaces are the same hex codes with an application that ghex.

Comment: The syntax isn't everything... make sure `factorio` is in your `$PATH`. And btw... the `Path` key doesn't do what you think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that always worked for me was putting the whole path in the *Exec* section as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Factorio
Exec=/home/[USERNAME]/Games/factorio/bin/x64/factorio
Terminal=false
```

I don't know excactly what the *Path* section is for - I never used it.

Comment: `Path` is documented on [freedesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html). It is the current working directory used when the application is executed. But it is not a search path for the executable given by `Exec` when its absolute path is not specified.

Comment: This is what worked for me. The thing is, I'm 99.99% sure I had tried this exact format before... whatever works, though!